# typo3 migration to new server not working

Tags: php, migration, typo3

I trying to move a typo3 website to a new server.I moved all the files across and created a new database and imported all the tables from the old database.  I then updated the localconf.php file with the new database settings.  However, I'm now getting a series of fatal errors which seem to be because the paths in the typo3 old website used a mixture of uppercase and lowercase letters, but on the new server all the files and folders are lowercase, and it is throwing an error whenever an internal path is using uppercase letters because it can't find the path or file.I don't know if this is particular to 1&1 who are my hosts.

Is there an easy way to fix this or do I have to go through all the internal code to change all the paths to lowercase?  Which seems a little unrealistic.  I was hoping I'd be able to transfer the website over in a few hours, but so far have spent about a day on it.  I also do not know typo3 at all, this is my first time with it.  Though I am experienced in setting up Drupal and Joomla websites and thought it wouldn't be so different.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Ben

EDIT - Additional information:

The error message I'm getting is:

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/htdocs/vincent/typo3conf/ext/formhandler/Resources/PHP/Hooks/class.tx_formhandler_stdwrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5') in /htdocs/vincent/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 5046

The line 5046 is the last line of code below. I don't know which path is being referred to in the $requireFile variable.

```
    /**
 * Require a class for TYPO3
 * Useful to require classes from inside other classes (not global scope). A limited set of global variables are available (see function)
 */
public static function requireOnce($requireFile)    {
    global $T3_SERVICES, $T3_VAR, $TYPO3_CONF_VARS;

    require_once ($requireFile);
}
```

Comment: I would first start with not making all file-names lowercase. It sounds as if you didn't either migrate to the same operating system or you didn't preserve the data. But this does not sound like a programming question. And please share the exact error messages and show some code where the error appears so it's more clear what this is about.

Comment: what kind of errors? Which path? fileadmin/somefolder/somefile.txt or link to a webpage? I guess its an server issue, never had such an problem. You cleared cache? removed cached files?

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. I've added additional information about the error above.

Comment: Can you check if the file is actually there?

Comment: Hi pgampe, I've just checked and all the files are there.

Comment: If this file exists /htdocs/vincent/typo3conf/ext/formhandler/Resources/PHP/Hooks/class.tx_formhandler_stdwrap.php on Your new server ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, the problem is in the cache, which was made on Your old installation. Check if typo3temp, typo3conf/temp_* files are removed.

If it will not work, pelase post here fatal errors You get. It will help to understand the nature of Your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried deleting the temp files in the typo3conf folder and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: You also need to delete all files and folders below `typo3temp/`.

Comment: Hi pgampe, thanks for your suggestion, I deleted everything inside typo3temp and it hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem by changing the names of any folders with uppercase letters to lowercase.

When I moved the site across I had used a zip file, and for some reason, when I unzipped the file it must have created some of the folder names using initial capitals and this is what had caused the problem.